# Can I connect to the server Ubuntu from the computer by pptp connect and then connect to the server mikro

Tags: 12.04

I have an Ubuntu server.

I have activated a pptp connection in it.

I connected a mikrotik server with claint PPTP connection to the Ubuntu server.

Can I connect to the server Ubuntu from the computer by pptp connect and then connect to the server mikrotik?

What is the way please ?

Note: When I make  ping between Mikrotik and ip pptp it is successful from both ends

Comment: Hi, could you specify little better. If I understand you correctly, you are making site to site vpn, and PPTP is not good for that. I would suggest making IPSEC tunnel between machines.

Comment: thank you my friend.
i have an Mikrotik server and i have Radius server in VPS I make connection between it by PPTP VPN  , it is successful.
And when i make connection by PC to Radius server by PPTP VPN 
also is successful.
NOW: I need to make connection between my PC and  Mikrotik server by PPTP VPN how i will do that?

Comment: if i make ping between *pptp server* 192.168.9.1 & *user1* 192.168.9.101 is succes
and if i make ping between *pptp server * 192.168.9.1 & * user2 * 192.168.9.102 also succes
but if i make ping between 192.168.9.101 &192.168.9.102 is faild